# hook_views_query_alter does not work when filters get applied

Tags: 6, views

I used the function `hook_views_query_alter` and altered the sql to get desired result. This works fine when the view loads for the 1st time. I have some exposed filters also. As soon as i apply exposed filers, the query alteration does not happen. Anything i have to do, if exposed filters have been applied..?